# Word VBA duplicating find and replace with tracking

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to run a Word VBA macro using Find and Replace on similar strings. It works perfectly with tracking off, but with tracking on I get repeats like CompanyCompany. It appears to performing the find/replace at the same time only when Tracking is turned on. I have hundreds of documents to go through so Tracking is a must. Any suggestions on how to avoid this?

```
Private Sub document_open()

With ActiveDocument 
 .TrackRevisions = True 
 .ShowRevisions = True 
End With

Dim rngStory As Word.Range
Dim lngValidate As Long
  lngValidate = ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(1).Range.StoryType
  'Iterate through all story types in the current document.
  For Each rngStory In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
    'Iterate through all linked stories.
    Do While .Found = True        
      With rngStory.Find

        .ClearFormatting
        .IgnoreSpace = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .Text = "Corporation"
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.Text = "Company"
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, _
        Wrap:=wdFindContinue
        
        .ClearFormatting
        .IgnoreSpace = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .Text = "Corp."
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.Text = "Company"
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, _
        Wrap:=wdFindContinue
        
        .ClearFormatting
        .IgnoreSpace = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .Text = "Corp"
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.Text = "Company"
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, _
        Wrap:=wdFindContinue

        
      End With
      
      
      'Get next linked story (if any).
      Set rngStory = rngStory.NextStoryRange
    Loop Until rngStory Is Nothing
  Next
  

End Sub
```

Comment: `Do While .Found = True` - it's unclear what the `With` block variable is that's qualifying this `.Found` member call. Or should the `With rngStory.Find` instruction be inside the `Do While...Loop` loop body? Note that `Do While...Loop Until` is illegal, looks like you have two different overlapping versions of the code going on here. As presented, this code cannot compile, let alone produce incorrect results. I'm not familiar with the Word object model, but is it possible that the 3 replacements need to be done in 3 distinct passes? "Corp" would be found in both "Corp." and "Corporation"...

Answer (score 0):

The following should work

```
Private Sub document_open()

With ActiveDocument
    .TrackRevisions = True
    .ShowRevisions = True
End With

Dim story As Range

For Each story In ActiveDocument.storyRanges
    Do While Not story Is Nothing
        With story.Find
            .Replacement.text = "Company"
            .Execute "Corporation", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            .Execute "Corp.", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            .Execute "Corp", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        End With
        
        Set story = story.NextStoryRange
    Loop
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I was able to switch up the order to make it work:

            Execute "Corp.", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            .Execute "Corp", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            .Execute "Corporation", Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            .Execute "Companyoration", Replace:=wdReplaceAll••••ˇˇˇˇ

Comment: Unfortunately at a larger scale and more string, this does not work. It still fails and repeats the word.